# Unity WebRequest.downloadProgress keep coming back

Tags: c#, web, unity-game-engine, webrequest

i'm trying to fetch some informations from my server, and now i wanna display the progress on a bar (Like a download bar) but the download progress keep coming and going.

**This is my funcion of recovery posts**

```
public IEnumerator RecoveryPosts(string username, string first_last_post, int id_post, Action<List<RecoveryPostsStruct>> Oncomplete)
{
    string postsJson = "";
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("RecoveryPosts",
        "{\"username\": \"" + username + "\"," +
        "\"first_last_post\": \"" + first_last_post + "\"," +
        "\"id_post\": \"" + id_post + "\"}");

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(URI_USER, form);
    Debug.Log("Execute".Tint(Color.yellow).Bold());
    FindObjectOfType<PostController>().StartCoroutine(ShowDownloadProgress(www));
    yield return www.Send();
    if (!www.isNetworkError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Success!\n<color=#00e640><b>Recupera Posts</b></color>\n");
        Debug.Log("Response:" + www.downloadHandler.text + "\n");
        postsJson = www.downloadHandler.text;
        if (postsJson != Util.ROUNDSTARS_ERROR)
        {
            List<RecoveryPostsStruct> listPostsStruct = new List<RecoveryPostsStruct>();
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            RecoveryPostsJson[] posts = JsonHelper.FromJson<RecoveryPostsJson>(postsJson);
            foreach (RecoveryPostsJson item in posts)
            {
                listPostsStruct.Add(new RecoveryPostsStruct(item.id_post, item.profilePicture, item.username, item.post, item.info_likes, item.qtd_comments, item.postPicture, item.date_post));
            }
            Oncomplete(listPostsStruct);
        }
    }
```

**and this is for show progress**

```
public IEnumerator ShowDownloadProgress(UnityWebRequest www) {
    while (!www.isDone) {
        if(LoadingScreen.instance != null)
            LoadingScreen.Fill(www.downloadProgress);
        Debug.Log(string.Format("Downloaded {0:P1}", www.downloadProgress));
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);
    }
    Debug.Log("Done");
}
```

**this is what i got from console**
[image]

**EDIT:**

this is the new ShowDownloadProgress:

```
public IEnumerator ShowDownloadProgress(UnityWebRequest www) {
    while (!www.isDone) {
        if(LoadingScreen.instance != null)
            LoadingScreen.Fill(www.downloadProgress);
        Debug.Log(string.Format("Downloaded {0:P1}", www.downloadProgress));
        yield return null;
    }
    Debug.Log("Done");
}
```

and this the new RecoveryPosts:

```
 public IEnumerator RecoveryPosts(string username, string first_last_post, int id_post, Action<List<RecoveryPostsStruct>> Oncomplete)
{
    string postsJson = "";
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("RecoveryPosts",
        "{\"username\": \"" + username + "\"," +
        "\"first_last_post\": \"" + first_last_post + "\"," +
        "\"id_post\": \"" + id_post + "\"}");

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(URI_USER, form);
    Debug.Log("Execute".Tint(Color.yellow).Bold());
    //Make request. Don't yield
    www.SendWebRequest(); 
    //Yield/wait in the ShowDownloadProgress until ShowDownloadProgress returns 
    yield return FindObjectOfType<PostController>().StartCoroutine(ShowDownloadProgress(www));
    if (!www.isNetworkError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Success!\n<color=#00e640><b>Recupera Posts</b></color>\n");
        Debug.Log("Response:" + www.downloadHandler.text + "\n");
        postsJson = www.downloadHandler.text;
        if (postsJson != Util.ROUNDSTARS_ERROR)
        {
            List<RecoveryPostsStruct> listPostsStruct = new List<RecoveryPostsStruct>();
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            RecoveryPostsJson[] posts = JsonHelper.FromJson<RecoveryPostsJson>(postsJson);
            foreach (RecoveryPostsJson item in posts)
            {
                listPostsStruct.Add(new RecoveryPostsStruct(item.id_post, item.profilePicture, item.username, item.post, item.info_likes, item.qtd_comments, item.postPicture, item.date_post));
            }
            Oncomplete(listPostsStruct);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Error: " + www.error);
    }
}
```

Comment: This means that you attached the download script multiple times to a GameObect, you attached it to multiple GameObjects or you called the download function multiple times. Always post your code when asking questions as your problem may be from there. Also add a screenshots to prove everything I said above wrong.

Comment: reformulated the question

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to use `www.isDone` only after calling `www.Send()` not before it. This is likely why it goes from 100 to 0. Also, do not yield `www.Send()` when you are using `www.isDone`. Only yield `www.Send()` if you don't care or need the progress of that request. Finally, wait or yield for the `ShowDownloadProgress` function until it returns before accessing the downloaded data or executing `if (!www.isNetworkError)`. Without waiting for the `ShowDownloadProgress` function, you will try to access the downloaded data while the download has not yet completed.

In the `RecoveryPosts` function, change

```
UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(URI_USER, form);
Debug.Log("Execute".Tint(Color.yellow).Bold());
FindObjectOfType<PostController>().StartCoroutine(ShowDownloadProgress(www));
yield return www.Send();
```

to

```
UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(URI_USER, form);
Debug.Log("Execute".Tint(Color.yellow).Bold());
//Make request. Don't yield
www.Send(); 
//Yield/wait in the ShowDownloadProgress until ShowDownloadProgress returns 
yield return FindObjectOfType<PostController>().StartCoroutine(ShowDownloadProgress(www));
```

---

In the `ShowDownloadProgress` function, change `yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);` to `yield return null;` so that you get the progress every frame instead of every `0.1` second.

Comment: i really got what you mean, but after all changes the progress still coming back, may this be an error on the server?

Comment: Add EDIT to your question then post your new fixed code for both functions. Do not remove the old one.

Answer (score 0):

i think it's the server problem. First i used google drive with direct download, and it run badly as the same problem as u. Then, i tried using github raw gists and it run normally, with no coming back.

[my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBkat.png)